# Anglo Concertina playing series of the same note press button multiple times or hold?

Tags: concertina

Hello I am a complete beginner with music and I am learning the Anglo concertina.

When you have a series of the same note do you release the button and press it again? Or stop the instrument and start while holding button?

Comment: I added that I am using the Anglo concertina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common technique here is to alternate two fingers on the same button.  That makes for better and faster articulation when it is applicable.  It can also provide an opportunity for getting into a better hand position for the next note.

Interrupting the air stream is a technique for comparatively soft start and ending of a note: it is not really called for in mid-phrase.

Unisonoric instruments (like some rare chromatic bandonions and chromatic accordions) can facilitate repeated fast direction changes for the effect that would be called "tremolo" with string instruments.  That is called a "bellows shake".  It doesn't really apply to bisonoric instruments like the typical concertina.  Other than that, you would not apply a bellows reversal as a note separation without also releasing the button/key in between.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a lot of concertina players think the type they play is "the typical concertina", when there are many kinds/systems.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it seems you just release the button and press it again.  There is an example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSTeUMHYn5k&t=170s) at the minute mark 2:50.